# Pulling Public Facebook Posts Into PHP Page

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Last December, I set up an app for a client who wanted to pull their public facebook posts into the footer of their website.

I was using this URL to pull the message, create time and permalink and when I wrote it, all was good:

http://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=SELECT%20message,%20created_time,%20permalink%20FROM%20stream%20WHERE%20source_id=138631878804%20AND%20message%3C%3E%27%27%20limit%203

Today they reported that it was no longer pulling their information.  I put that url into a browser and the result is "Requires valid signature"

I've gathered from google that I need something called an access_token, also I've seen where I can use the php sdk but then I need an appId and a secret token.

At this point, I've read so many different sources that I am thoroughly confused.  The FQL query above represents the full extent of my Facebook programming experience.  It looks like maybe I want the Graph API, but I don't want anyone to have to sign into anything.

Can one of you guys who are more versed in the voodoo of facebook nudge me in the right direction to do this:

From PHP, pull public messages from the stream table without forcing a user to log into facebook.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To pull posts from a publicly visible Page on Facebook, you can use any valid access token.  For most sites managing a page, this will be a page access token retrieved via one of the page's admins authorising your app to have access to their pages, but that might be overkill for your use-case.

Probably the quickest solution is to just create a new App ID for the site, get the app access token for that App (see 'App Login' on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/ ) and then use that access token to retrieve the posts.

Comment: Ok, so just to make sure I understand you correctly, I would have my client sign into their facebook account and create a new app for their website.  Then I would use the appid and secret from that app to generate an access_token per the App Login section of the documentation?

Comment: Yes, I think that's the fastest way to get what you want. You can use any access token, including one generated by the Graph API Explorer ( https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=533875325 ) - the main reason to use an App access token is that they're not tied to a user session so you can use them as long as the App Secret isn't changed

Comment: Thank Igy, I really appreciate your insight. I wasn't sure which part of their documentation pertained to what I was trying to do, but what you've suggested makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I found several links all from a simple Google search.

Duplicate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3298836/how-you-get-access-tokens-for-facebook

http://benbiddington.wordpress.com/2010/04/23/facebook-graph-api-getting-access-tokens/

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

Comment: I've read those already.  I'm confused on the various idioms that facebook is using.  For example, does the owner of the facebook page have to create an app just to allow someone to pull their public posts?  I really have read the documentation, I just don't yet grok what they're getting at.  From what I keep reading, they keep talking about users signing in, access tokens expiring, etc.  .  Honestly, posting here was the last resort, not the first.

Comment: AFAIK you create an app, and then use the app to get an access token, API key, or whatever credentials you need to access the API. It's quite un-elegant to create an app only to get an access token - not that app creation is difficult, it's only a few clicks. Yet that seems to be the standard expectation and it's a pretty straightforward procedure.